# figure printing in matlab using function handle

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Hi I would like to do the following in Matlab

Suppose I have a function which plots something

```
function # call 1
function # call 2
function # call 3
function # call 4
```

Consider that all the above functions will plot a figure in matlab window. How can I write the functions such that it will save the figure somewhere and then I can use something like this -

```
subplot(2,2,1), # plot for call 1
subplot(2,2,2), # plot for call 2
subplot(2,2,3), # plot for call 3
subplot(2,2,4), # plot for call 4
```

I do not want to save the individual figures in memory and the again load it.

A very simple function is like this :

```
x = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
y = sin(x);
xmarkers = 0:pi/2:2*pi; % place markers at these x-values
ymarkers = sin(xmarkers);
figure
plot(x,y,'b',xmarkers,ymarkers,'b*')
```

If I call this multiple times it will generate multiple figures, I want to put it into a subplot format.

Comment: Can you show the functions?

Comment: Is it clear now. Kindly tell me. Otherwise I will further explain it.

Comment: You can also read the docs. It is all right there, http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html

Comment: Thanks. But @patrik could you write it in the form of an answer ?

Comment: @roni The answer given covers the most. It was just a pointer to some good documentation. Since a figure is unique it is seen as a resource. This means you have to save the handle in a variable. In case the given answer does not help you need to explain the problem further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a script `myplot.m`, which calls the function `myfunction`:

```
fig_handle1 = figure;
gcf

fig_handle2 = figure;
plot(1:10);
gcf

myfunction( fig_handle1, 1 );
myfunction( fig_handle1, 4 );
```

It creates two figures and stores the handles in `fig_handle1` and `fig_handle2`. The first figure is not used, the second figure is used to plot a ramp. `gcf` tells you which figure is currently active. As you want to `plot` to the first figure in `myfunction`, you will have to pass the correct figure handle. The second argument will tell, which subplot to use:

The content of the function `myfunction.m` looks like:

```
function myfunction(fig_handle, subplot_no)
    set(0,'CurrentFigure', fig_handle)

    x = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
    y = sin(x);
    xmarkers = 0:pi/2:2*pi; % place markers at these x-values
    ymarkers = sin(xmarkers);

    subplot(2, 2, subplot_no);
    plot(x,y,'b',xmarkers,ymarkers,'b*');
end
```

It uses `set(0,'CurrentFigure', fig_handle)` to set the current figure to your first figure and then uses `subplot(2, 2, subplot_no);` to select the subplot you want. `plot` will then draw to your first figure.

Calling `myplot` from the command line gives you the following result:

[image: Figures 1 and 2]

Use the debugging functionality to step through the code and see what happens.